# boundingrectwithsize not working with linebreakmode: NSLineBreakByWordWrapping

Tags: ios, objective-c

`boundingrectwithsize` returning size according to `NSLineBreakByCharWrapping`. `boundingrectwithsize` returns perfect size only if I use `NSLineBreakByCharWrapping`. Researched every where at google but no luck. I am using following code to get size using `NSLineBreakByWordWrapping`.

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraph = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
paragraph.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;

CGSize size = [label.text boundingRectWithSize: constrainedSize options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes: @{ NSFontAttributeName: label.font, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraph } context: nil].size;
```

Comment: And what is the Problem? Or what do you want to implement specifically?

Comment: When I try to set text in `UILabel` using `NSLineBreakByWordWrapping ` it overflows and displays `...` at the end of label.

Comment: I used the same method without the `NSParagraphStyleAttributeName` option and it gave me the correct size, without cropping words. I can post the code, if you want.

Comment: Actually when we test it for specific text with longer words, more are the chances to produce endlines for wordWrap mode, which results in increased height.